# Pandas WHERE clause for string index?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a table, `ss_prices`, which has a primary key column called `fund_code` that `pandas` treats as the index:

```
>>> arr = list(zip(['MM1', 'MM2', '3MM', '4AA'], range(1,5)))
>>> cols = ['fund_code', 'values']
>>> ss_prices = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=cols).set_index('fund_code')
>>> ss_prices
              values
    fund_code
    MM1       1
    MM2       2
    3MM       3
    4AA       4
```

I want to get only those rows where the primary key starts with 'MM'.  In SQL I can do:

```
select * from ss_prices
where left(fund_code, 2) = 'MM'
```

But in `pandas` it seems I have to do:

```
ss_prices[np.vectorize(lambda x: x[:2] == 'MM')(ss_prices.index.values)]
```

The `pandas` syntax is certainly more confusing and less readable.  Short of using a tool like [pandasql](https://github.com/yhat/pandasql), is there a more readable way of accomplishing a `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to filter on the index using a regular expression:

```
In [5]: ss_prices
Out[5]:
     values
MM1       1
MM2       2
3MM       3
4AA       4

In [6]: ss_prices.filter(regex='^MM', axis=0)
Out[6]:
     values
MM1       1
MM2       2
```

Comment: Beautiful!!  I wish SQL could do regular expressions like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `x.startswith("MM")` (and you should, see [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)).

Comment: Like this?  `ss_prices[np.vectorize(lambda x: x.startswith('MM'))(ss_prices.index.values)]`?  That's a little more readable, I agree, but not by much.  I was hoping for something like `ss_prices.where(lambda x: x.startswith('MM'), axis=0)`

Comment: @MichaelCurrie Yes, that's the best I can say.

Answer (score 1):

Try `df.index.to_series().str[:2]`:

```
In [324]: df
Out[324]:
     a
MMa  1
MMb  2
AAA  3
BBB  4

In [325]: df[df.index.to_series().str[:2] == 'MM']
Out[325]:
     a
MMa  1
MMb  2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html#pandas.Series.str.startswith) directly on the index to return a boolean mask:

```
In [27]:
df[df.index.str.startswith('MM')]

Out[27]:
     a
MMa  1
MMb  2
```